# Can my mobile site send coordinates to the mobile phone's navigation app?

Tags: php, mobile, navigation

I have recently heard that a mobile website can push coordinates to the mobile phone's navigation app (or at least make it ask the user if they want to open it with their navigation app).  I've done some google searching to no avail.  I'm not sure if I'm just not using the right keywords or what, but I can't find this information.  Does anyone know anything about this ability?  And if so, can you give some links or examples?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit for a better understanding**

I'm looking for a way to push a location to the navigation app so that the user can get driving directions. So the website will have a location of a shop, the user clicks the shop, it asks if they want to open their navigation app to get driving directions there, they press yes and are taken to the navigation app with the shop's location set.

Comment: What do you mean by mobile app ? mobile web , mobile java, mobile ios etc ? What are you using to develop your mobile application ? What Mobile Navigation app are you talking about google map , yahoo map , black berry map ????

Comment: @Baba I've never used the term "mobile app", so I'm not sure what you mean.  The first line says "mobile website".  But as for the navigation app I would like to open the location in, it's whatever navigation app they may have installed.  Similar to how opening a PDF on a mobile device can cause the device to automatically ask what you would like it to open the PDF with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to do so is to pass data to Google or iOS maps - probably some other navigation apps are providing some url schemes but you're not able to check if such app is installed from browser level. When Google/iOS maps url is called inside browser Android/iOS will open proper application.

For Android and iOS <= 5 phones (for desktops also) you can just open URL:

```
// for example from JS
location.href = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr="+destination;

// or from PHP
header('Location: https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr='.$destination);
```

For iOS6 you can use similar address but change domain from `maps.google.com` to `maps.apple.com`.

Comment: This seems to work for me.  I don't mind checking to see if they are on IOS or Android as long as it does what I need it to do.  Thanks a lot.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

> The Geolocation API defines a high-level interface to location information associated only with the device hosting the implementation, such as latitude and longitude. The API itself is agnostic of the underlying location information sources. Common sources of location information include Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input. No guarantee is given that the API returns the device's actual location.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a way to push a location to the navigation app so that the user can get driving directions.  So the website will have a location of a shop, the user clicks the shop, it asks if they want to open their navigation app to get driving directions there, they press yes and are taken to the navigation app with the shop's location set.  I'll update my question in case that wasn't clear.  Thanks for the response though.